# How to document functions that are assigned, rather than defined?

Tags: python, functional-programming, documentation

When using functional programming in Python, I'm finding myself declaring functions with assignment, *e.g.*

```
where = compose(pluck(0), filter(get(1)), enumerate)
```

rather than using `def`, *e.g.*

```
def where(seq):
    """Return the indices of truthy values in a sequence."""
    return pluck(0, filter(get(1), enumerate(seq))
```

The first method is elegant and terse, but there's no docstring, which is unacceptable. The second method allows for a docstring but is less elegant, and less in the functional style.

**What's the best practice for documenting functions created by assignment in Python?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a means by which you can document such functions in Python; however, it's not considered good practice to do so. Despite how `def fun` doesn't seem in the functional style unfortunately for now at least, it seems to be the best practice. The workaround can be seen below:

```
where = compose(pluck(0), filter(get(1)), enumerate)
where.__doc__ = """some docstrings here"""
```

Comment: I considered that but also determined it was inadequate, as you say. I'll stick with `def` for now. Thanks!